# How to display help screen when developing a CLI app using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a CLI app using Spring. One of the things I would like to do is to be able to display a help/usage screen like the way you can do it with [commons-cli](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html):

```
// automatically generate the help statement
HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
formatter.printHelp("ant", options);
```

How to do this with Spring? Or is Spring not the right tool for developing a CLI app?

When comparing `commons-cli` with Spring, I feel that with `commons-cli` you cannot auto-parse a config file whereas with Spring you can auto-parse config file but its support for parsing command line arguments is clunky (e.g., boolean flags can't be turned on by just typing `--flag1`); in fact I haven't been able to use command line arguments successfully at all with Spring (`-Dspring-boot.run.arguments`)